# How can I hide "Recently Viewed Opportunities" list view for some users?

Tags: security, list-view

I need to hide the "Recently Viewed Opportunities" list view from all users other than admin. While searching I found that, this list view can not be edited. Does this also mean that it cannot be made hidden?

**Update:**
See below attached image:
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the dropdown selection on the opportunity landing page or are you talking about the Recent Opportunities section on the opportunity landing page?

Comment: @BlairKristin the dropdown on opportunity tab (landing page)

Comment: I believe this is technically the `Opportunity Tab  Search Layout` - not a list view (although it sure looks like a list!) - you can reduce the number of fields shown

Comment: @crop1645 Added image to question to make it more clear!

Comment: ah, sorry I misunderstood -- once user has selected some other view, their browser remembers what they chose and they won't see recently Viewed by default anymore

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to wipe your items out. It is a semi-popular idea on the boards which I would recommend you vote up (I know I did!)

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpzKAAS

Wish I had some better news for you, but at least you know!

Best of luck!

Comment: The linked idea does not seem very relevant as it is about "Customization of list view" rather than ability to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Train users on the value of "Recently Viewed" and how with only **one** additional click, they can see any list view desired
2. Create a custom VisualForce page and redirect the standard tab to the new page.  This will require you to constantly maintain/monitor changes with each new salesforce.com release.  Also, you will have to perform re-work each time your business needs change, such as a new field added/deleted.

Comment: I can not go with option # 2 because it will need to be maintained as you stated.

Comment: I figured.  I face this exact problem and determined it was best to help users understand it.    I don't want to get in the game of manage customized code/pages... never fun,

Comment: Yeah, your are right. lets hope salesforce shows mercy on us and provide this functionality!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a list view and you are not able to edit it, then it probably means that it is owned by someone else. You would have to login as that user to edit. To find out who created the list view, try the following:

1. Login to Workbench.developerforce.com with your salesforce credentials.
2. For "Jump To:" select "Metadata Types & Components"
3. Click on the "Select" button.
4. In the "Choose a metadata type describe and list its components:" dropdown select "Listview"
5. Click on the "Expand All" link and press CTRL+F on your keyboard. In Salesforce go to the listview you are trying to find the owner of and copy the ID value in the browser and paste it into the find search box on the Workbench page.
6. Remember that more than one value may appear because in Salesforce they put the 15 character case sensitive id in the browser and Workbench shows the case insensitive 18 character id. You can go to the id field of the result in workbench and if you haver over it there is an option to view in Salesforce. Use this if more than one result comes up. If more than one result does come up it should still be only a few results.
7. It will show you the Name of the person that created it. Login as that user and only give admins access.

Comment: This is salesforce's default list view.